# Signing/Publishing iOS App from another Mac

Tags: ios, macos, cordova

I've read a bunch of threads, posts and articles but I didn't find what I'm looking for.

My friend has a apple dev account where I can generate the certs and such. This account is not a company account if that matters.

Currently I'm working on a ionic/phonegap app and it's ready for testing. There is a step when creating the certificate that needs to open the crt file within Keychain Access and export a file. <-- Is this step mandatory on the Mac of the dev account holder? or Can I do it with my own Mac? Will it affect somehow? We've 3 apps published already but I always use his to do this steps and he is currently unavailable.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have your friends's Apple dev certificate ?

Comment: @SauvikDolui no. I always did it on his mac. I never take any file with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with any mac, but the private key will be on that specific mac. You can then later share it.

However, your friend can export his/her dev account and share it with you, giving you everything you should need.

Comment: Ah, okey. I have to wait for him to return then. I never made a copy of those files.